# Adding extra host to dockerfile

Tags: docker

I am trying to build and run a docker container of one of my services from the Dockerfile. I need to add some extra host to the container. I know that in the docker compose file you can add:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "DEV01:172.16.0.10"
  - "DEV02:172.16.0.11"
  - "DEV03:172.16.0.12"
```

However I need to build the image directly from the docker file. How do I add these extra hosts?

I have tried add `--add-host=[]` to the `docker run` which some people have suggested but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Typically you'd want to add name-to-IP address mappings in a DNS server, rather than replicating them by hand in multiple places.  You cannot specify run-time settings like this in a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

Docker run with --add-host works fine:

```
->docker run --rm \
 --add-host="DEV01:172.16.0.10" \
 --add-host="DEV01:172.16.0.11" \
 --add-host="DEV01:172.16.0.12" \
 alpine cat /etc/hosts
```

Gives output:

```
 127.0.0.1  localhost
 ::1    localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
 fe00::0    ip6-localnet
 ff00::0    ip6-mcastprefix
 ff02::1    ip6-allnodes
 ff02::2    ip6-allrouters
 172.16.0.10    DEV01
 172.16.0.11    DEV01
 172.16.0.12    DEV01
 172.17.0.3 e85457b446f1
```